# Can't load Oracle.dll for module DBD::Oracle: load_file:%1 is not a valid Win32 application at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 201

Tags: oracle, perl

I'm getting this error in connecting to oracle DB.

[image: This is the error I'm getting]

This is my sample code.

```
#!usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:host=sample.com;sid=sampleid;port=1522', 'local', 'local');
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Perl but perhaps speicifying the Os you're on (32/64 bits) and Oracle Client version (if installed) will help here

Comment: Have you installed [DBD::Oracle](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Oracle) ?

Comment: I'm using 64 bit OS windows 10.

Comment: Do you need separate installation for DBD::Oracle? I thought when I installed perl it will automatically install DBD::Oracle?

Comment: Having problem in installing DBD::Oracle.. https://imgur.com/CtVvyWn
What does this mean?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are in Windows.

Your first line should be something like:

```
#!C:\perl64\bin\perl
```

instead of

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
```

Comment: Since OP runs their script with `perl connect.pl` (and not `./connect.pl`), the path in the shebang is ignored by Perl. The only things Perl looks at on the shebang line are the flags.

Comment: Also, shebangs are ignored in Windows completely (aside from using flags from it).